# Pygame .rotate is making a surface grow rather than rotate

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm trying to make a program generate graphs and I'm trying to make the square rotate just for something later on, but the squares are growing rather than rotating even though I'm using pygame.transform.rotate().

```
import pygame, json
from pygame.locals import *

with open("data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)


running = True
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
angle = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size=(800,600))
while running:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    for i in range(0,len(data["x"])):
        surf = pygame.Surface((50,50))
        surf.fill((255,0,0))
        surfrect = surf.get_rect()
        surfrect.x = (data["x"][i])
        surfrect.y = (data["y"][i])
        surf = pygame.transform.rotate(surf,angle)
        screen.blit(surf,(surfrect))
    pygame.display.flip()
    angle += 1
    print(angle)
    if angle == 90:
        angle = 0 

pygame.quit()
```

And the data for anyone who wants to try it:

```
{"x":[100,200,300], "y":[100,200,300]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a *Surface* with a per pixel alpha format (see [How can I make an Image with a transparent Backround in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623341/how-can-i-make-an-image-with-a-transparent-backround-in-pygame/62623422#62623422)):

<s>`surf = pygame.Surface((50,50))`</s>

```py
surf = pygame.Surface((50,50), pygame.SRCALPHA)
```

See also [How do I rotate an image around its center using PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144)

```py
import pygame, json
from pygame.locals import *

with open("data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

running = True
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
angle = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size=(800,600))

original_surf = pygame.Surface((50,50), pygame.SRCALPHA)
original_surf.fill((255,0,0))

while running:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    for i in range(0,len(data["x"])):
        surf = pygame.transform.rotate(original_surf, angle)
        surfrect = surf.get_rect()
        surfrect.centerx = (data["x"][i])
        surfrect.centery = (data["y"][i])
        screen.blit(surf,(surfrect))
    pygame.display.flip()
    angle += 1
    print(angle)
    if angle == 90:
        angle = 0 

pygame.quit()
```