# Problem with images overlapping in pygame

Tags: image, pygame, rect

Im having problems with blitting images to rect objects in pygame. i have a background image blitted to my main pygame window, and also an image blitted to a rect object on the screen which moves. the problem i am having is the rect object is overlapping my background image when its moving around. i was looking to only be able to see the green helicopter shape and not the black outline around it. sorry if i havent explained this very well. will try to include all files im using.
Thanks for any help

```
import pygame as pg
import random as r
import time
pg.init()



MAX_X = 1190
MAX_Y = 590
MIN_X = 10
MIN_Y = 10
SIZE = 100
SPEED = 1
COLOR = (0,255,0)
move_amount = 0



wn = pg.display.set_mode((1200, 600))

BG_IMG = pg.image.load('bg.png').convert()
BG_IMG = pg.transform.scale(BG_IMG, (1200, 600))

class Wall (pg.Rect):
    def __init__(self, posX, posY):
        self.xcor = posX
        self.ycor = posY
        self.rect = None

class Heli (pg.Rect):
    def __init__(self, posX, posY):
        self.image = pg.image.load('art.png').convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
        self.xcor = posX
        self.ycor = posY
        

# top and bottom constant walls
TOP = pg.Rect(MIN_X, MIN_Y, MAX_X, 3)
BOTTOM = pg.Rect(MIN_X, MAX_Y, MAX_X, 3)


heli = Heli(MIN_X, MAX_Y //2)


# keep moving walls in a list
moving_walls = [Wall(MAX_X, r.randint((MIN_Y + 10), (MAX_Y - 10)))]




# main loop
while True:
    # fill screen
    wn.fill('black')
    

    # editing objects to move

    

    # blitting must happen before everything else
    
    pg.draw.rect(wn,COLOR, heli.rect)
    
    wn.blit(BG_IMG, (0,0))
    wn.blit(heli.image, heli.rect)

    heli.rect.y += move_amount
    heli.rect.y += 1

    # use a variable to control how much movement is happening
    # movement happens continuosly
    # if key down it  oves if key up it doesnt
    

    
    for wall in moving_walls :
        wall.rect = pg.Rect(wall.xcor, wall.ycor, 3, SIZE)
        pg.draw.rect(wn, COLOR, wall.rect)
        wall.xcor -= SPEED

        if wall.xcor < MIN_X + 10:
            wall.xcor = MAX_X
            wall.ycor = r.randint((MIN_Y), (MAX_Y - SIZE))
        
    # drawing all objects back to the screen



    pg.draw.rect(wn, COLOR, TOP)
    pg.draw.rect(wn, COLOR, BOTTOM)


    # update window
    pg.display.update()

    # event handling
    for ev in pg.event.get():
        if ev.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if ev.key == pg.K_UP:
                move_amount = -3
        if ev.type == pg.KEYUP:
            move_amount = 0
                
        if ev.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 1):

You discard the transparency information of the image. You have to use `convert_alpha` instead of `convert`:

<s>`self.image = pg.image.load('art.png').convert()`</s>

```py
self.image = pg.image.load('art.png').convert_alpha()
```

The pygame documentation notes that:

> The returned Surface will contain the same color format, colorkey and alpha transparency as the file it came from. You will often want to call [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) with no arguments, to create a copy that will draw more quickly on the screen.
> For alpha transparency, like in .png images, use the [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) method after loading so that the image has per pixel transparency.

See also [How can I make an Image with a transparent Backround in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623341/how-can-i-make-an-image-with-a-transparent-backround-in-pygame/62623422#62623422)